# How to get the name of File in a directory in C#

Tags: c#

```
Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
```

Using the above code we get the names(**i.e full path)** of all the files in the directory. but i need to get only the name of the file and not the path. So how can I get the name of the files alone excluding the path? Or do I need to do the string operations in removing the unwanted part?

EDIT:

```
TreeNode mNode = new TreeNode(ofd.FileName, 2, 2);
```

Here `ofd` is a `OpenFileDialog` and `ofd.FileName` is giving the the filename along with it's Path but I need the file name alone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use:

```
Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
```

or in your example:

```
TreeNode mNode = new TreeNode(Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName), 2, 2);
```

Comment: TreeNode mNode = new TreeNode(ofd.FileName, 2, 2);

here ofd is OpenFileDialog and ofd.FileName is giving the the filename along with its Path but i need the file name alone.

Comment: Path.GetFileName(fullPath); will work for a single file, the Q states all the files in the directory

Comment: @Rashmi Pandit - but then he talks about getting the filename from the OpenFileDirectory dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Use DirectoryInfo and FileInfo if you want to get only the filenames without doing any manual string editing.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 foreach(FileInfo fi in files)
 {
     Response.Write("fi.Name");       
 }
```

Comment: You should probably have left the other answers, as they cover the two best alternatives.

Comment: your answer is out of context.  the question has nothing to do with ASP.NET

Comment: @ck and @adam, the question has nothing to do with console apps either, but you accept that?