# How can I get only the file name part from a path string?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the name of File in a directory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862416/how-to-get-the-name-of-file-in-a-directory-in-c-sharp)

For example if I have:

`d:\test\text.txt` or `d:\test\test5\test.bmp`

I want that in for example `string t` to have only `text.txt` as a string
or that `t` will be `test.bmp`

So `t` will contain only the file name part from the path string.

The code:

```
public WmvAdapter(string file, string outFolder)
{
    path_exe = path_exe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
    histograms_dat_fileName = "histogramValues.dat";
    histograms_dat_filenameRGB = "histogramValuesRGB.dat";
    histograms_dat_fileName_Directory = path_exe + "\\" + "dat file";
```

I want that if file is for example `d:\text\text.txt`
So

```
histograms_dat_fileName_Directory = path_exe + "\\" + "dat file";
```

will be:

```
histograms_dat_fileName_Directory = path_exe + "\\" + "dat file" + "\\" + "text.txt";
```

So when I create the file later it will be in the directory for example:

```
c:\myuser\appdata\local\dat file\text.txt\
```

`text.txt` is a path\folder not a text file I want it to be created as a path.

Today the path is for example: `c:\myuser\appdata\local\dat file`

But I want to create another path to each file name.

Comment: Have you tried to google it at least?

Comment: Why not use `System.IO.Path.Combine()`, much easier than combining strings manually.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How to get the name of File in a directory in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/862416/299327). Please search SO before posting a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

`Path.GetFileName(@"d:\test\text.txt")`

Returns `"text.txt"`

Answer (score 3):

Use `Path.GetFileName` and `Path.Combine`:

```
string path = Path.Combine(path_exe, "dat file", Path.GetFileName(file));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName("d:\\test\\test5\\test.bmp");
// fileName now contains "test.bmp"
```